# How can I avoid an ffmpeg out of memory error

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, out-of-memory

I use ffmpeg with complex filtering. Input are different sets of FULLHD surveilance camera videos each 10 to 15 seconds long. Set size (number of videos per set) varies. To remove unchanged frames I apply mpdecimate. To avoid being triggered by moving bushes but still keep objects I want to remain, I apply a complex filter:

- split the video (the original and a dummy to detect motion/stills)
- scale the dummy down (so the 8x8-block-metric of mpdecimate matches the size of moving objects I want to keep)
- add white boxes to dummy to mask unintendedly moving objects
- apply mpdecimate to dummy to remove non-changing frames
- scale dummy back to original size
- overlay the remaining frames of dummy with matching frames of original

All this works fine if the number of input videos is small (less than 100). The memory consupmtion of the ffmpeg process varies somewhere between 2GiB and 5GiB.

If the number of input files gets larger (say 200), the memory consumption suddenly jumps to insane numbers until memory (32GiB plus 33GiB swap) runs out and ffmpeg gets killed. I can not predict if and why this happens. I have one example, where a set of 340 videos worked using 6GiB. Any other set above 100 videos I tried eats all RAM in under two minutes and dies.

There is no particular error message from ffmpeg.

dmesg says:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 29173 (ffmpeg)
Killed process 29173 (ffmpeg) total-vm:66707800kB
```

My ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vidlist -vf 'split=2[full][masked];[masked]scale=w=iw/4:h=ih/4,drawbox=w=51:h=153:x=101:y=0:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=74:h=67:x=86:y=49:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=51:h=149:x=258:y=0:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=13:h=20:x=214:y=103:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=29:h=54:x=429:y=40:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=35:h=49:x=360:y=111:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=26:h=54:x=304:y=92:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=48:h=27:x=356:y=105:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=30:h=27:x=188:y=124:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=50:h=54:x=371:y=7:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=18:h=38:x=248:y=107:t=fill:c=white,drawbox=w=21:h=51:x=242:y=33:t=fill:c=white,mpdecimate=hi=64*80:lo=64*40:frac=0.001,scale=w=iw*4:h=ih*4[deduped];[deduped][full]overlay=shortest=1,setpts=N/(15*TB),mpdecimate=hi=64*80:lo=64*50:frac=0.001,setpts=N/(15*TB)' -r 15 -c:v libx265 -preset slower -crf 37 -pix_fmt yuv420p -an result.mkv
```

ffmpeg version 4.1.6

Debian 4.19.171-2

I hope that my filter can be tuned in some way that achieves the same result but doesn't eat RAM that much - but I have no clue how. Within reasonable limits, I wouldn't mind if processing time suffers. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if this is helpful, but I once ran into problems because one of my vids had a crazy (corrupted) frame rate and resolution. It blew up the process. Since your scaling seems to be non-linair, you might want to rule out you have a faulty file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How could I check that for lets say 900 files and what do I need to look for? Using my ffmpeg command from above but without the filters, everything works and memory usage stays below 500MiB. So if the source videos have some corruption it must be one that breaks the filter but not ffmpeg or x265. No clue what to look for.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you want to test the correctness and stability of your filter. The first step would be to rule out any issues with the input. For this you can 500 copies of a file of which you know it works. If it fails, and by your statements I am afraid it will, you're sure it's due to your filter - and you can start the big memory leak hunt.

Comment: I tested different sub-sets of my filter. The problem seems to be the drawbox filters. With my entire ffmpeg command (as in the question) but without any of the drawboxes it uses 6GB, with one drawbox its 11GB, with two its 12GB, with three its 20GB and with four its 50GB. My intended filter uses twelve drawbox filters... Seems the number of drawbox filters increases memory use exponentially. Any recommendations?

Comment: It's good to hear you've pinpointed the leak. You'll need to isolate the problem. You can do this by analyzing a memory dump (that's quite hard without proper tools). If you have access to the code, you can start disabling parts of it to pinpoint the cause. Everything with graphics is a suspect. Graphics needs to be released from memory after use. Make sure you release, free, delete or dispose the graphical objects - this can be images, device contexts, brushes, pens, lines, --- basically everything graphical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! I understand your words but the action is beyond me. I am afraid I am unable to dig deeper.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry to hear it didn't help you. Do know; I am not an FFMPEG expert, maybe their public forums, or the developer of the filter can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the memory issue can be avoided by removing the split filter. Instead of spliting one input into two streams (that ffmpeg has to store in memory) the same input can be loaded twice.

So instead of using "full" and "dummy" as below

```
ffmpeg -i source -vf 'split=2[full][dummy];...;[dummy][full]overlay...
```

one would use "0:v" and "1:v" as in

```
ffmpeg -i source -i scource -filter_complex '.....;[0:v][1:v]overlay...
```

I get this to work with input videos, but so far [I fail to do this with the concat demuxer as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728350/how-to-use-concat-demuxer-twice-in-the-same-ffmpeg-command).

**Any hints very welcome.**