# how to use concat demuxer twice in the same ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

For a complex ffmpeg filter I need the same input twice. For the sake of simplicity I will use a sample where I just overlay a video with itself. (In my real problem the filter is more complex):

```
ffmpeg -i vid -i vid -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]overlay' -c:v libx265 -an result.mkv
```

This works, the result is the reencoded original video.

Sadly, my input is not a video file but a concat demuxer. This is my naive aproach:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i vid_list -f concat -i vid_list -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]overlay' -c:v libx265 -an result.mkv
```

And it fails. I get tons of error messages about missing frames and the resulting video is completely wrong.

**How can I use concat demuxer twice as input within the same ffmpeg command?**

NB: loading the concat only once and then using the [split filter doesn't work for me. In combination with my complex filter it consumes all RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66724106/how-can-i-avoid-an-ffmpeg-out-of-memory-error).

Comment: Have you tried generating a combined file using `-c copy` and reading that twice?

Comment: that is, what I hoped ffmpeg can do for me on the fly without doubling the source. The source is quite big compared to the resulting file.... I will try your suggestion and if there is nothing better I could do, try to cope with that. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: copy doesn't work on my source. the best (speed vs space vs quality) I found so far is ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vidlist -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -an temp.mkv but obviously an on-the-fly solution would be better in all three categories.

Comment: How does copy not work? What is the error shown?

Comment: the resulting file is not playable and not ffmpeg readable: "ffmpeg -f concat  -safe 0 -i vidlist3  -c:v copy -an result.mkv"       gives me "Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly"

Comment: Your second command works fine for me. Make sure to use a build from the current git master branch, show the complete log from your command, and show detailed info for each input listed in `vid_list` (the output of `ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2` will suffice).

Comment: Your confirmation that this should work inspired me to dig deeper. See my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @Silentfury While it's good you found a solution if you provide the requested info on your inputs we can point out the cause of the original problem and perhaps give you a better solution.

Comment: @llogan: well, the problem doing that starts with "use a build from the current git master branch". I see this somewhere between hard and impossible.......

Comment: @Silentfury You can just download a recent, already compiled build for Windows, Linux, or macOS. See the links in [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assertion from llogan above, that my idea should work, I found a solution that I don't 100% understand but it seems to work....

The input videos do not all have the same framerate. I didn'T expect this to be important, since I am using the very same list of videos twice, so whatever the framerate is or what the concat demuxer does to it, it should be the same to both. Still, explicitly setting the input frame rate seems to solve my problem.

So this fails:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i vidlist -f concat -safe 0 -i vidlist ...
```

but this works:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -r 15 -safe 0 -i vidlist -f concat -r 15 -safe 0 -i vidlist ...
```

As said I don't understand exactly why...

Thanks to all